# Serre's criterion and closure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a projective scheme of pure dimension $n \ge 2$. Let $U$ be an open dense subset of $X$ such that $\mathrm{codim}(X\backslash U,X) \ge 2$ and for all points $x \in U$, $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ satisfies Serre's criterion $S_2$. Is it then true that $X$ satisfies $S_2$?

Comment: Certainly not. If $X$ is regular in codimension 1 then your hypothesis holds. But if $X$ is not normal then it is not $S_2$, by Serre's theorem (normal=R1+S2).

Comment: I do not understand. R1+S2 is normal. So why does not normal imply not S2?

Comment: If $X$ is R1, then it is normal iff it is S2.